# how to add a button column in the right hand side of the datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

i am new with WPF

i have a datagrid to display some data from the database. i want a column in the right hand side of the datagrid for displaying buttons.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_search_by_device" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Button x:Name="btn_serch_device_History" Content="History"></Button>
                                                            <Button x:Name="btn_search_device_Details" Content="Details"></Button>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

this is what i did in my xaml code.

```
private void Search_Device_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         DataTable _return;             
        Search_device urlData = new Search_device(int.Parse(Device_ID.Text));
        _return = Calibration.PrepareCommand.Search_by_device(urlData);

        DataView view = new DataView(_return);
        DataTable _data = view.ToTable("Selected", false, "LastCalibratedDate","SensorReplacement");
        _data.Columns["LastCalibratedDate"].ColumnName = "Last Calibrated Date";
        _data.Columns["SensorReplacement"].ColumnName="Sensor replacement";
        try
        {
            if (_data.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Nodata.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                DG_search_by_device.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DG_search_by_device.ItemsSource = _data.DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                Nodata.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DG_search_by_device.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

this is my cs file.

i got buttons in the left hand side of the datagrid. but i need it in the right hand side. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `AutoGeneratedColumns` event of the `DataGrid` .

```
private void DG_search_by_device_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dgrd = sender as DataGrid;
            {
                var c = dgrd.Columns[0];
                dgrd.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                dgrd.Columns.Add(c);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if i have two buttons in two different columns. and i want both columns in the right hand side. what i can do?

Comment: use same approach with diff columns